# Programa com Recursão em C

Tags: c, recursão, codeblocks, dev-c++

Preciso fazer um program a que se trata de um jogo, onde o usuário irá colocar como input um número e eu devo determinar se é possivel o usuário ganhar o jogo através de um printf dizendo "Sim" ou "Nao", não é nescessário mostrar os passos do programa.
O jogo se baseia nas seguintes regra:

*Se o número for par se retira metade do número;

*Se o número for multiplo de 3 ou 4 se multiplica os 2 ultimos digitos do numero e subtrai-se de seu total;

*Se o número for multiplo de 5 subtrai-se 42 dele;

O objetivo do jogo é terminar com o número 42 se não você perde.
Segue um exemplo abaixo:

1-Você começa com 250.

2-Como 250 é divisível por 5, você pode tirar 42, deixando como resto 208.

3-Como 208 é par, você pode tirar metade do total, deixando 104 como resto.

4-Como 104 é par, você pode tirar metade do total, deixando 52 como resto.

5-Como 52 é divisível por 4, você pode multiplicar os dois últimos digítos de 52 (resultando em 10) e excluir 10. Isso te deixa com 42 de resto.

Pronto! O objetivo foi alcançado! Note, entretanto, que tanto no passo 2 como no passo 5, você poderia ter usado a regra do n par. Em ambos os casos, você perderia.

por enquanto tenho o seguinte código:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int teste1(int num);

int main(){
int num;
int finalNum;
int dado;

scanf("%d",&num);
if(num>=42){

finalNum = teste1(num);
if(finalNum != 42){
        }
 }
 printf("%d",finalNum);
 }

int teste1(int num){
int newNum;
int once;
int i;
int count;

count = 0;

once = 0;

if(once == 0){
    newNum = num;
    printf("%d,%d\n",newNum,num);
    once = 1;
}
if(newNum >=42){

if(newNum % 2 == 0){
    newNum = teste1(newNum-(newNum/2));
}
else if(((newNum % 3 == 0) || (newNum % 4 == 0)) &&  ((newNum%100)/10)*(newNum%10) > 0){
        newNum = teste1(newNum - ((newNum%100)/10)*(newNum%10));
        int dado1 = ((newNum%100)/10)*(newNum%10);
        /*450*/     
}
else if(newNum % 5 == 0){
    newNum = teste1(newNum - 42);
}
}

return (newNum);
}
```

meu problema por enquanto é que meu código primeiro faz a verificação se o número é par então se por acaso o número for par e multiplo de 5 o programa irá apenas fazer a verificação de número par então no caso do exemplo acima meu programa não consiguirá dizer que é possivel vencer.
A única maneira que pensei de arrumar esse problema é executar o "void test1" várias vezes, porem mudando qual verificação devo fazer primeiro, mas como não posso usar nenhum tipo de estrutura de repetição nesse código não consegui pensar em alguma maneira inteligente de resolver o problema a não ser criar vários void com seguencias de verificação diferentes. Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1):

Essa resposta não tem a intenção de resolver o problemas, mas sim mostrar um caminho pra solução.

A ideia seria criar quatro funções independentes.
Cada uma retorna se ganhou ou não.

Primeira função (f1)

- Verifica se o número é igual a 42, se sim retorna ganhou.
- Se o numero for menor q 42 retorna não ganhou.
- Senão retorna f2 ou f3 ou f4. Se alguma função retornar que ganhou então retorna ganhou.

f2 - Se o número for par se retira metade do número;

f3 - Se o número for multiplo de 3 ou 4 se multiplica os 2 ultimos digitos do numero e subtrai-se de seu total;

f4 - Se o número for multiplo de 5 subtrai-se 42 dele;

Para a implementação desta (f2,f3,f4) faz o seguinte:

- Se a condição for verdadeira então realiza a condição e desse novo numero retorna f1 deste.
- Senão retorna não ganhou.